# Как в Java сделать генератор случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне?

Tags: java

Имеется переменная z типа int. Её надо приравнять случайному числу от 100 до 239.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(239 - 100) + 100
```

Comment: @SKYLINEGTR обратите внимание, что 239 не будет включено.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я догадался)