# Случайное число в диапазоне от -10 до 10 в Java.

Tags: java

Друзья, приветствую!

Необходимо сгенерировать случайное число в диапазоне от -10 до 10.
nextInt() не позволяет этого.
Подобный вопрос [задавался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16221/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-java-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5), но не могу осилить написанное (мне необходим код целиком).

Не так давно начал изучать Java, не будьте строги.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тогда, видимо, нужно выбросить книгу, по которой Вы учитесь, если не можете написать что-то вида:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i<1000;i++) {
            int q = r.nextInt(21) - 10;
            System.out.println(q);
        }
    }
}
```

А вот почему там 21 и 10 - это уже домашнее задание.

**Обновление**

Random принимает параметром seed - такой специальный параметр для генерирования последовательности. В многих языках функция random сделана так, что если начальное значение одинаковое, то и последовательность будет одна и та же.

Это сделано в целях отладки и детерминированности (то есть чтобы все было стабильно и повторяемо) программ.

А вот задание в качестве seed текущего времени (которое не повторяется) дает возможность генерировать разные последовательности.

Comment: Никогда не понимал, разработчики сделали именно так.

Comment: Потому как в java нет обычных функций. Только классы с методами.

Comment: Сэнсэй, большое спасибо! ) Домашнее задание выполнено. int q = r.nextInt(21) - 10; //из генерируемого диапазона (от 0 и до 21) будет вычитаться 10. Что при мин. значении nextInt (при 0) будет давать -10 и макс. (при 20) 10, что нам и требуется. Но этот метод не подойдет, например, при мин. -510 и макс. 10. Для этого можно использовать формулу int num = min + r.nextInt(max - min + 1);

Если можно, еще вопрос - почему используется запись 
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()); , а не
Random r = new Random(); ? Работает одинаково.

Comment: @Darmidont, в данном случае не имеет значения, но это число - seed, инициализирует генератор псевдослучайной последовательности, элементы которой вы будете получать. По сути если вы посмотрите исходники конструктора Random() без параметров, там используется вызов System.nanoTime() для инициализации.

Comment: Обновил ответ